# AWS environment variables does not work with ECR get-login

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecr

Am I configuring environment variables for the default user, but it does not work with `aws ecr get-login` why?

```
> export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=SOMEID
> export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=SOMEID
> sudo aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region eu-west-1
```

This gives the error:

> Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running
> "aws configure".

Using AWS configure resolves the issue. However, I would like to use environment variables instead.

- I can see the environment variables are set and correct using `env`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `sudo` doesn't pass your local environment variables to the root process it spawns. You have to tell it to pass those environment variables to the process with the `--preserve-env` argument.

Or just set the values on the same command:

```
sudo AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=SOMEID AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=SOMEID aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region eu-west-1
```

Comment: Wow, that's super nice to know!